Microsoft Graph Search API no longer returns OneDrive files when searching with application permissions
I am working with the Microsoft Graph Search API. I was previously able to set a region in my request for the driveItem entity type and get back results for both OneDrive and SharePoint, but just today, it started only returning SharePoint results. Is this the expected behavior now? If it is, this has some very bad effects on my application.
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "entityTypes": [
                "driveItem"
            ],
            "query": {
                "queryString": "test"
            },
            "region": "NAM"
        }
    ]
}

This used to return thousands of results, most coming directly from OneDrive accounts. I've tested it in the Microsoft Graph Explorer with delegated permissions and no region property and I get back all of the results. But when I test it using Postman and application permissions, it returns 4, all of which come from SharePoint. Is there a permission I need to set in my Entra app registration to get more than just the SharePoint results again?

It seems that there was just a bug with this endpoint and Microsoft has straightened itself out.
